# Which I must learn? Pylons vs Pyramid?

Tags: python, frameworks, pyramid, wsgi, pylons

Which framework is better pyramid vs pylons? what similarities do they have? which of them must I learn. I learn django actively and I want to learn pyramid or pylons also.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is primarily opinion based, and as such, is off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 4):

Pylons Project Team made a web framework called Pylons
Pylons Project Team made a new web framework called Pyramid, not derived from Pylons, is derived almost entirely from repoze.bfg
Pylons is shifted into 'legacy' status.

SO Going for Pyramid is better.

You have other options like Flask also.